# tikz-cd commutative diagram special form

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

[image]

I am using the `tikz-cd` package. How can I draw the above diagram in LaTeX?

Comment: It is just a 4x4 matrix, the rest is explained in the tikzcd manual (note this site is not a `please do this for me service`, it is for concrete questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because I wanted to see exactly how fast one could do this with the package manual in hand, here is the diagram in tikz-cd:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % incase you're using babel
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    {}
    &
    {}
    &
    A
    \ar[ld,hook']
    \ar[rd,"f"',"\cong"]
    &
    {}
    \\
    B'
    \ar[r,hook]
    &
    B
    \ar[rd,"s"',"\cong"]
    \ar[rdd,bend right,"j"']
    &
    {}
    &
    C
    \ar[ld,hook',"h"]
    \ar[ldd,bend left,"k"]
    \\
    {} & {} & D & {}
    \\
    {} & {} & E & {}
    \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

- Bendy arrows, manual page 3
- Hook arrow, manual page 4 note the syntax for hook up/down
- The syntax for the labels including the `"..."'` syntax is covered on page 2 in the manual

See also egregs answer for tips on how to further adjust the look

[image]

Comment: It's nice when all relevant information is in the first four pages of a manual `:-D`

Answer (score 6):

Just a few adjustments to make the square a square and the bottom vertical row a bit longer.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2.5em]
&& A \arrow[ld,hook'] \arrow[rd,"f","\cong"']
\\
B' \arrow[r,hook] &
B \arrow[rd,"\cong","g"'] \arrow[rdd,bend right,"j"'] &&
C \arrow[ld,hook',"h"] \arrow[ldd,bend left,"k"]
\\
&& D \arrow[d]
\\[0.5em]
&& E
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `"<symbol>"'` (note the quote) we say to typeset the symbol on the opposite side to the arrow; the default one is the left side as determined for rivers. With `hook'` the hook is reversed (it usually bends to the left side). Similarly one determines when `bend left` or `bend right` is needed.